# Webflux - return Flux or error after a condition

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm learning reactive programming with webflux, and for that I'm migrating some code.

For example I'm trying to migrate this method:

```
public Set<Vaccine> getAll(Set<Long> vaccinesIds) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        if (null == vaccinesIds) {
            return null;
        }

        Set<Long> vaccinesToFind = new HashSet<>(vaccinesIds);
        vaccinesToFind.remove(null);

        Set<Vaccine> vaccines = new HashSet<>();
        vaccineRepository.findByIdIn(vaccinesToFind).forEach(vaccines::add);

        if (vaccines.size() != vaccinesToFind.size()) {
            LOG.warn("Could not find vaccines with ids: " + vaccinesToFind.removeAll(vaccines.stream().map(Vaccine::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(VACCINE_ERROR_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return vaccines;
    }
```

To summarize the code, if the respository returns all the vaccines that are requested should return the result, if not should return an error.

For that, I thought in something like this, but is not working:

```
public Flux<Vaccine> getAll(Set<Long> vaccinesIds) {
    if (null == vaccinesIds) {
        return Flux.empty();
    }

    Set<Long> vaccinesToFind = new HashSet<>(vaccinesIds);

    Flux<Vaccine> byIdIn = vaccineRepository.findByIdIn(vaccinesToFind);
        
    Mono<Long> filter = vaccineRepository.findByIdIn(vaccinesToFind).count().filter(x -> x.equals(Long.valueOf(vaccinesToFind.size())));

   return filter.flatMapMany(asd -> vaccineRepository.findByIdIn(vaccinesToFind)
    ).switchIfEmpty(Flux.error((new EntityNotFoundException(VACCINE_ERROR_NOT_FOUND))));
   
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

My first doubt is why the filter is a Mono of Long if it has a equals method in the end. My problem is about evaluating the filter in order to return the list or the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are querying the same result `vaccineRepository.findByIdIn(vaccinesToFind)` multiple times. The same data is queried, transferred  and deserialized multiple times. This is a sign that something is wrong here.

Let's assume the result set fits into the memory. Then the idea would be to transform flux into a usual collection and to decide whether to emit an error or not:

```
return vaccineRepository.findByIdIn(vaccinesIds)
.collectList()
.flatMapMany(result -> {
    if(result.size() == vaccinesIds.size()) return Flux.fromIterable(result);
    else return Flux.error(new EntityNotFoundException(VACCINE_ERROR_NOT_FOUND));
});
```

In the case the result is to huge for the main memory, you could do count in the db by the first query and in the positive case query the results. The solution is similar to your code:

```
return vaccineRepository.countByIdIn(vaccinesIds)
.filter(count -> count == vaccinesIds.size())
.flatMapMany($ -> vaccineRepository.findByIdIn(vaccinesIds))
.switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new EntityNotFoundException(VACCINE_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)));
```

The result of `filter` is `Mono<Long>` because filter just takes the elements from the upstream and tests against the given predicate. If the predicate returns false, the item is filtered out and the `Mono` is empty. To keep all results of a the test you could use `map` and the type would be `Mono<Boolean>`.

Comment: Thank you very much @gindex, very useful answer!